# How to "scroll" a scrollbar in qml?

Tags: macos, qml

I'm new in qml. Does anybody know how to manipulate a scrollbar from qml? I only found this: `scrollbar.increase()` but I would want to move the scrollbar to the end of its limit in one move e.g. having scrolled to the top I want to move in one moment to the bottom of my page.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting `position = 1.0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually scroll anywhere you want by setting the `position` property, which is in the range of 0.0-1.0. So to scroll to the bottom, simply do this:

```
position = 1.0;
```